# How to prove the Poincaré inequality by induction on the dimension?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, functional-inequalities

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Lipschitz boundary and $1\leq q \leq \infty$. By the Poincaré inequality, there is $c>0$ such that

$$\|u\|_{L^q(\Omega)} \leq c \|\nabla u \|_{L^q(\Omega)}$$

for any $u \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ satisfying $\int_\Omega u=0$. I would like to find a demonstration for it that uses induction on $n$. The reason is that I am trying to prove it in a different class of spaces than $L^q$ (in which I have already checked that the case $n=1$ holds), and I think the proof in $L^q$ spaces would serve as a kind of guidance.

The classical proof for it uses compact embeddings, which I am avoiding since I do not know if they hold in my class of functional spaces. As for a proof by induction, until now, I have found it only under the hypothesis that $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ instead of $\int_\Omega u=0$.

Do you guys know some references?

Comment: I am a bit confused. How would you do induction? How do you deal with the domain? The constant depends on the domain in question.

Comment: I assume that you want to do some kind of slicing. If that is the case, then you would need to have a constant that holds true for all the slices (which I wouldn't know how to do).

Comment: Yes, I guess such proof would be based on some kind of slicing. Normally, the constant does not depend on the domain itself, but only on its diameter. So the constants for the slices would be bounded in terms of the diameter of the original domain.The proof I have mentioned (in which it is supposed u=0 on the boundary) uses only the case n=1 to extend for general n (so it is not a proof by induction).

Comment: You say that the constant only depends on the diameter, however, isn't this restricted to the case where the domain is convex? Do you have a source where they prove this in the generality you claim? I thought that the issue is that you could get closer to forming cusps which messes with the constant.

Comment: Lemma 3.2.2 in [Qing Han](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-120) gives the above-mentioned proof (supposing u=0 on the boundary and using the case n=1 to extend for general n) in L2.

Comment: p.s.: The domain is not necessarily convex (but he supposes it with C1 boundary, while I'm supposing only Lipschitz).

Comment: p.p.s.: As for the possible formation of cusps, since the domain has a Lipschitz boundary (and so does each slice), it would not be possible.

Comment: In the source, they only prove the case where the function vanishes on the boundary. If you consider the case where the average should vanish, isn't that more complicated? Consider for example $\Omega = [-1,1]^2 \setminus (\{0\} \times [-1+\varepsilon, 1-\varepsilon])$. Then you can consider functions that are essentially $1$ on the upper part and $-1$ on the lower part. The derivative will vanish on most of the set and if you make $\varepsilon$ smaller and smaller it seems to me that the inequality gets worse and worse.

Comment: Probably I should use $\Omega = [-1,1]^2 \times ([-1,1]\setminus \{0\}) \cup ([-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]^2\times \{0\})$. If you take $u =1$ on the upper part and $-1$ on the lower part and interpolate linearly on the interface and then smooth it a bit, you should get $\vert \nabla u \vert \leq C/\varepsilon$ on a set of measure of the order $\varepsilon^3$ (and zero elsewhere). Thus, I should be able to make the $L^2$ norm of $\nabla u$ as small as I like (it's of order $\varepsilon$), but the $L^2$ norm of $u$ will stay of order $1$.

Comment: The inequality would fail if you could choose functions with a jump. By removing part of the domain, you are essentially allowing jump discontinuities. This does not happen if you restrict yourself to convex domains.

Comment: Yes, I have understood your counterexample. Convexity is necessary when only the condition about the mean is required. And, since my domain does not fulfill that, I guess I'll try to figure out other approaches. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. You may want to consider posting a new question including the function space you are really interested in. There are some people here (or on mathoverflow) that might be able to help you.